# How to save a list of doubles using Aspnet webapi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I need to save a list of locations from a point A to B from android client, I'm using WebApi with EntityFramework and SQL Server. In android project, I'm using the class `LatLng` and make a List of these locations, so I was thinking of Transform the Object latLng in JSON and save as string, it would be a good way to storage this?

```
public List<LatLng> buildJSONRoute(String jsonRoutes) throws JSONException {...

latLngs = buildJSONRoute(s);
String routes = new Gson().toJson(latLngs);
```

Comment: Store where? For what reason? For how long? How will you use it? Will you need to transform the data? Will you need to search the data? ...

Comment: Store in SQL Server using WebApi. How long? Permanent. The user will be able to get this List and use to draw the route with android maps. I will need to parse to `LatLng` class to be able to draw! The query of that list will be return with another user data, not the list it self. I'm just trying to avoid consume Google Api Routes, since I already have the list of locations, the second time that I need to request again, i just list them and parse.